# Problem involving pointers and manually implemented matrix classes

Tags: c++, class, pointers, matrix, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm currently working on a bigger project which involves implementing a linear algebra calculator. I have decided to not use any other already-existing libraries which might help me implement it as I thought it would be too easy.

I first started to code the Matrix class, which now looks like this:

```
class Matrix{
private:
    int rows; // no. rows
    int columns; // no. columns
    double** matVal; //values of the matrix
    char name; //only used when printing it out or by outside programs.
public:
    //constructors and destructor
    Matrix();
    Matrix(int r,int c,char _name);
    ~Matrix();

    //basic get functions for private access
    int getNrRows();
    int getNrCols();
    char getName();
    double getVal(int row,int col);

    //basic set functions for private variables
    void setVal(int row,int col,double value);
    void setName(char _name);

    //basic matrix operations
    Matrix operator=(Matrix M);
    Matrix operator+(Matrix M);
    Matrix operator-(Matrix M);
    Matrix operator*(Matrix M);

    //Printing out the matrix
    void Print();
};
```

At first it went smoothly, but then I stumbled into a fatal bug which wont allow me to progress further. For more information, here are my functions ( + some code to try to figure out what's wrong) and what I executed in main():

```
#define cout std::cout

Matrix::Matrix(){
    rows = 0;
    columns = 0;
    matVal = nullptr;
}

Matrix::Matrix(int r,int c,char _name){
    rows = r;
    columns = c;
    name = _name;
    matVal = new double*[r];
    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++){
        matVal[i] = new double[c];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < c; j++){
            matVal[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

Matrix::~Matrix(){
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        delete[] matVal[i];
    delete[] matVal;
}

int Matrix::getNrRows(){
    return rows;
}

int Matrix::getNrCols(){
    return columns;
}

char Matrix::getName(){
    return name;
}

double Matrix::getVal(int row, int col){
    return matVal[row-1][col-1];
}

void Matrix::setVal(int row,int col,double value){
    matVal[row-1][col-1] = value;
}

void Matrix::setName(char _name){
    name = _name;
}

Matrix Matrix::operator=(Matrix M){
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        delete[] matVal[i];
    delete[] matVal;

    rows = M.rows;
    columns = M.columns;

    matVal = new double*[rows];

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        matVal[i] = new double[M.columns];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < M.rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < M.columns; j++){
            matVal[i][j] = M.matVal[i][j];
            cout<<matVal[i][j]<<' ';
        }
        cout<<'\n';
    }
    cout<<this<<std::endl;
    return *this;
}

Matrix Matrix::operator+(Matrix M){
    Matrix Rez;
    Rez.rows = rows;
    Rez.columns = columns;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
            Rez.matVal[i][j] = matVal[i][j] + M.matVal[i][j];
        }
    }
    return Rez;
}

void Matrix::Print(){
    cout<<'\n';
    cout<<name<<": "<<"\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
            cout<<matVal[i][j]<<' ';
        }
        cout<<'\n';
    }
    cout<<'\n';
    return;
}
```

Main:

```
Matrix M(4,3,'A');
M.setVal(1,1,2);
M.setVal(1,3,-1.1);
M.Print();
Matrix A(4,3,'B');
A.setVal(3,2,5);
A.Print();
Matrix C(4,3,'C');
C = A;
cout<<C.getVal(3,2)<<'\n';
cout<<C.getNrCols()<<" "<<C.getNrRows()<<endl;
C.Print();
cout<<"S"<<endl;
```

Printing the first 2 matrices works fine, when I print each element of C in the operator= function after I assigned it the proper value, again, it works fine, but when I use the Print() function on C it crashes. Here is the console output for the code above:

```
A:
2 0 -1.1
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0


B:
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 5 0
0 0 0

0 0 0
0 0 0
0 5 0
0 0 0
0x69fed0
5
3 4

C:
```

At first I had absolutely no idea why it did that, but then I printed the pointer to each variable instead(it printed it all and returned 0 this time):

```
A:
0x850e38 0x850e40 0x850e48
0x851318 0x851320 0x851328
0x851338 0x851340 0x851348
0x851358 0x851360 0x851368


B:
0x851390 0x851398 0x8513a0
0x8513b0 0x8513b8 0x8513c0
0x8513d0 0x8513d8 0x8513e0
0x855b08 0x855b10 0x855b18

0x855b40 0x855b48 0x855b50
0x855b60 0x855b68 0x855b70
0x855b80 0x855b88 0x855b90
0x855ba0 0x855ba8 0x855bb0
0x69fed0
5
3 4

C:
0 0x8 0x10
0 0x8 0x10
0 0x8 0x10
0 0x8 0x10

S
```

Now I think that there is a problem with the Print function (because otherwise why would I be able to get the 5 printed out in main?). I still don't know exactly what is happening so I ask for your help. I'm sorry if this is a rookie mistake, I'm still quite inexperienced.

I also forgot to add that the class and class functions are in separate files (header and cpp), although I don't know how this could affect things.

Comment: You should check  if (this != &M) in operator= overloading because you will do all that operations with the same object

Comment: Why not a vector instead of a double pointer

Comment: Also in operator+ you should pass const Matrix& M because you will work with the copy of the object when use it

Comment: [C++ Matrix Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076624/c-matrix-class)

Comment: Also, look up "rule of three".  The gist is that, if manually defining one of an assignment operator, a copy constructor, or a destructor is needed,  then it is necessary to implement all three.   You've implemented an assignment operator and destructor, but not a copy constructor.   In C++11 and later, the rule of three becomes the rule of five.   Not following these rules eventually gives undefined behaviour when an object that manages a resource (e.g. dynamically allocated memory in your case) is copied.

Comment: @NixoN I don't understand why I should pass const Matrix& M instead of Matrix M, will I work with a copy of M or of the "this" object?

Comment: @Marius, passing by value is fine if you then return that same value after adding `*this` to it. Also note that `operator=` should return `*this` by reference or just be `void` if don't need chaining of assignments.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Operators: Canonical implementations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations).

Comment: @Peter I suppose the rule of five is "null" constructor, constructor, copy constructor, destructor and assignment operator?

Comment: @Marius, that is the rule of zero. :)

Comment: When you pass a `Matrix` by value the copy contains the same pointers as the original. When the copy goes out of scope the destructor will `delete[]` those pointers. So you get dangling pointers in the original `Matrix` and a double free of those pointers.

Comment: @Marius - if by "null" you mean "not explicitly defined by the programmer" then, as Evg noted, what you describe is the rule of zero.   If your class explicitly manages a resource (as distinct from the resource being managed properly by bases or members of the class) then you can't follow the rule of zero.   The rule of zero is preferred because it amounts to using existing classes to manage resources, rather than needing to roll your own resource management - and possibly getting it wrong (as you have, because you didn't follow the rule of three).

Comment: "I have decided to not use any other already-existing libraries which might help me implement it as I thought it would be too easy." in that case, you'll find that there are a few containers that you keep repeating over and over. One of those is definitely vector. If you don't want to use `std::vector`, write your own and use it. If you're picking up carpentry but don't want to buy a mallet because it would be "too easy", you don't decide to use your fists on every piece of furniture. You build a mallet. Build a `marius::vector<T>` class. It doesn't need to be complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature `Matrix operator=(Matrix&);` proposed in another answer it totally wrong. The correct signature should be

```
Matrix& operator=(const Matrix&);
```

or

```
void operator=(const Matrix&);
```

if you don't need chaining of assignments (`a = b = c`).

The bare minimum that you have to implement: copy constructor, copy assignment, and destructor. For a matrix class it is also reasonable to implement move operations. This is known as [the rule of zero/three/five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) (it is five in our case):

> If a class requires no user-defined constructors, no user-defined assignment operators and no user-defined destructor, don't define them; if a class requires a user-defined destructor, a user-defined copy (and move) constructor, or a user-defined copy (and move) assignment operator, it almost certainly requires all three (five).

Let's assume that matrix internally is represented as a 1D array. This approach avoids unnecessary indirection for matrix element access and simplifies code.

```
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(const Matrix&);
    Matrix(Matrix&&);

    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix&);
    Matrix& operator=(Matrix&&);

    ~Matrix();

private:
    double* data_        = nullptr;
    std::ptrdiff_t rows_ = 0;
    std::ptrdiff_t cols_ = 0;
};
```

Copy operations should be **deep**, i.e. they should copy data, not just underlying pointer. Let's start with a copy constructor. It should allocate storage, then copy data from `other` to this storage:

```
Matrix(const Matrix& other) 
: rows_(other.rows_), cols_(other.cols_) {
    const auto n = other.rows_ * other.cols_;
    data_ = new double[n];
    std::copy(other.data_, other.data_ + n, data_);
}
```

Now let's implement `swap`:

```
void swap(Matrix& other) {
    std::swap(rows_, other.rows_);
    std::swap(cols_, other.cols_);
    std::swap(data_, other.data_);
}
```

This function is very useful, because it allows us to implement move constructor, copy assignment and move assignment with almost no code:

```
Matrix(Matrix&& other) {
    swap(other);
}

Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& other) {
    Matrix(other).swap(*this);
    return *this;
}

Matrix& operator=(Matrix&& other) {
    Matrix(std::move(other)).swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

With such canonical implementations you can be sure that these functions are implemented correctly (including self-assignment handling) once you have correct implementations of copy constructor and `swap`. Appreciate the elegance of the [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

Now let's talk about `operator+`. Take a look at this implementation:

```
Matrix operator+(Matrix other) const {
    assert(rows_ == other.rows_);
    assert(cols_ == other.cols_);

    const auto n = rows_ * cols_;
    for (std::ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        other.data_[i] += data_[i];
    return other;
}
```

Here we take the argument by value and get a (deep) copy of it. Then we add `this->data_` to the copy and return that copy. There is no need to introduce another local `Matrix` variable.

[Complete demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Zj6vXw)

Answer (score 0):

you can change the operator= function to this form:

```
Matrix operator=(Matrix &M);
```

and in definition you should change its return to:

```
return M;
```

i checked this and worked.
in operator+(and *) consider this note too.

Comment: For me it worked by only changing the return *this to return M. Thank you very much!

Comment: Canonically this is a move-assignment, which should not copy the matrix, but move resource ownership from `M` to the current instance. Returning `M` will Break operator chaining. Returning by value is wrong, because you return a copy of `M` which can cause double deletion and dangling pointers again. I guess it seems to work because the unused return value is optimized away. Look at EVGs answer for a canonical and correct Implementation.